# How to disable scroll when export mat-table?

Tags: angular, scroll, mat-table, exporter

When I use exporter.exportTable() on a mat-table, visually, the data is scrolled till the end of the table. Please help :)!

Comment: Can you provide more details? What `exporter` is?

Comment: I am using the mat-table-exporter (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-table-exporter) so on a button in my html I attached this: (click)="exporter.exportTable('csv', {fileName: exportFileName}) and add to my mat-table element -->  <mat-table matTableExporter #sort="matSort" #table [dataSource]="dataSource" #exporter="matTableExporter"matSort matSortDisableClear>